# Update thread variable (c++)

Tags: multithreading, c++11

The actual problem is, that i try to send a new parameter to a running thread.
The idea was to change a variable in the thread, which did not work.
The code should display an easy example of the problem.
The printed variable test should be 1 after updating, but it is always 0.
Does anybody understand the problem and can help?
Thanks a lot!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class MyThread {
public:
int test = 0;
void operator()() const {
    while (1)
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
}
/* other public or private class members */
};

int main() {
    MyThread mythread;
    std::thread t(mythread);
    mythread.test = 1;
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler might see that your test variable do not change in the course of the method so it's stored in a register try to make it volatile instead: volatile int test = 0;

Comment: This is called a *data race*. Your code has undefined behaviour. Programming with concurrency is subtle and requires great care.

Answer (score 1):

Access to a variable from multiple threads must be made with an a special type of variabe called an "atomic."  In this case, since it's an int, it should be written as `std::atomic<int> test;`.

You can read more about the technical details of atomics and the C++ memory model [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model).

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion, you should declare your `test` integer member as `volatile`.

```
volatile int test = 0;
```

You've got 2 threads which are accessing the same variable. Without declaring volatile, compilers may optimize the memory read/write access which can lead to such effect.

Comment: This is incorrect because it fail to recognise cache coherency issues with multi-threaded programs running on multi-CPU systems.  Please read about Memory barriers - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier

Comment: I totally agree with your mentionned points. I just wanted to point out **one**  aspect in order the requester understand the multithreading complexity. The correct answer is as already mentionned `std::atomic<int> test;`

Comment: `volatile` is the solution for pretty much nothing these days in C and C++. Just about the only place it still has a legitimate use is in device drivers for relatively unsophisticated embedded system. There it's used prevent optimisations around reads and writes to memory where they have non-standard semantics (e.g. FIFOs, clear-on-read status registers and so on). On more sophisticated ones, you'd probably abstract the memory access away, use barriers, and have mapped IO as non-cachable address space.